# Array select and store using the C++ API

Tags: c++, z3

I am using z3 v 4.1. I am using the C++ API and I am trying to add some array constraints in the context.

I dont see the select and sort functions in the C++ API. I tried mixing of the C and C++ API. In the example `array_example1()` provided with the C API if I change the context variable from `Z3_Context` (i.e. C API) to `context` (i.e. C++ API) I get a segmentation fault at the "create antecedent" statement

```
void array_example1(){

context ctx; //Z3_context ctx; 
Z3_sort int_sort, array_sort;
Z3_ast a1, a2, i1, v1, i2, v2, i3;
Z3_ast st1, st2, sel1, sel2;
Z3_ast antecedent, consequent;
Z3_ast ds[3];
Z3_ast thm;

printf("\narray_example1\n");
LOG_MSG("array_example1");

//ctx = mk_context();

int_sort    = Z3_mk_int_sort(ctx);
array_sort  = Z3_mk_array_sort(ctx, int_sort, int_sort);

a1          = mk_var(ctx, "a1", array_sort);
a2          = mk_var(ctx, "a2", array_sort);
i1          = mk_var(ctx, "i1", int_sort);
i2          = mk_var(ctx, "i2", int_sort);
i3          = mk_var(ctx, "i3", int_sort);
v1          = mk_var(ctx, "v1", int_sort);
v2          = mk_var(ctx, "v2", int_sort);

st1         = Z3_mk_store(ctx, a1, i1, v1);
st2         = Z3_mk_store(ctx, a2, i2, v2);

sel1        = Z3_mk_select(ctx, a1, i3);
sel2        = Z3_mk_select(ctx, a2, i3);

/* create antecedent */
antecedent  = Z3_mk_eq(ctx, st1, st2);

/* create consequent: i1 = i3 or  i2 = i3 or select(a1, i3) = select(a2, i3) */
ds[0]       = Z3_mk_eq(ctx, i1, i3);
ds[1]       = Z3_mk_eq(ctx, i2, i3);
ds[2]       = Z3_mk_eq(ctx, sel1, sel2);
consequent  = Z3_mk_or(ctx, 3, ds);

/* prove store(a1, i1, v1) = store(a2, i2, v2) implies (i1 = i3 or i2 = i3 or select(a1, i3) = select(a2, i3)) */
thm         = Z3_mk_implies(ctx, antecedent, consequent);
printf("prove: store(a1, i1, v1) = store(a2, i2, v2) implies (i1 = i3 or i2 = i3 or select(a1, i3) = select(a2, i3))\n");
printf("%s\n", Z3_ast_to_string(ctx, thm));
prove(ctx, thm, Z3_TRUE);

}
```

I also tried converting `st1` and `st2` from `Z3_AST` to `expr` and then equating them but I still get the segmentation fault. How do I use select and store using the C++ API?

Answer (score 2):

Z3 has two memory management modes: push/pop and reference counting. Reference counting was introduced much later. The C API method used to create the `Z3_Context` defines which memory management mode will be used. The API `Z3_mk_context` creates a context where a `push/pop` policy is used. That is, AST objects are deleted when `Z3_pop` is invoked. Any AST object created between the matching `Z3_push` will be deleted. This policy is simple to use, but it may prevent your application from freeing unused memory. The API `Z3_mk_context_rc` creates a context where reference counting is used to reclaim memory. This is the official approach in Z3 4.x. Moreover, new objects (e.g., tactics, solvers, goals) introduced in Z3 4.x only support this approach.
If you are using C++, C#, OCaml, or Python APIs. Then, it is very simple to use the new reference counting policy. On the other hand, the C API is harder to use because we have to explicitly invoke the `Z3_*inc_ref` and `Z3_*dec_ref` APIs. If we miss one of them, we can have crashes (as in your example) or memory leaks.
In the C++ API, we provide several "smart pointers" that manage the reference counters automatically for us.

Your example crashes because you replaced `Z3_context ctx` with `context ctx`. The constructor of the class `context` uses `Z3_mk_context_rc` instead of `Z3_context`. The file `example.cpp` in the c++ directory demonstrates how to combine the C++ and C APIs (see function `capi_example()`). In this example, the C++ smart pointer are used to wrap the C objects returned by the C API.

Finally, the C++ API provided the following functions for creating array expressions:

```
inline expr select(expr const & a, expr const & i) {
    check_context(a, i);
    Z3_ast r = Z3_mk_select(a.ctx(), a, i);
    a.check_error();
    return expr(a.ctx(), r);
}
inline expr select(expr const & a, int i) { return select(a, a.ctx().num_val(i, a.get_sort().array_domain())); }
inline expr store(expr const & a, expr const & i, expr const & v) {
    check_context(a, i); check_context(a, v);
    Z3_ast r = Z3_mk_store(a.ctx(), a, i, v);
    a.check_error();
    return expr(a.ctx(), r);
}
inline expr store(expr const & a, int i, expr const & v) { return store(a, a.ctx().num_val(i, a.get_sort().array_domain()), v); }
inline expr store(expr const & a, expr i, int v) { return store(a, i, a.ctx().num_val(v, a.get_sort().array_range())); }
inline expr store(expr const & a, int i, int v) { 
    return store(a, a.ctx().num_val(i, a.get_sort().array_domain()), a.ctx().num_val(v, a.get_sort().array_range())); 
}
```