# for all quantifier in Z3

Tags: c, z3

I would like to see an example of C-API `Z3_mk_forall_const()` in Z3.

I am trying to encode -

```
(define-fun max_integ ((x Int) (y Int)) Int 
    (ite (< x y) y x))
```

What I tried is following, but I get `type error`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <z3.h>


void error_handler(Z3_context c, Z3_error_code e)
{
    printf("Error code: %d\n", e);
    printf("Error msg : %s\n", Z3_get_error_msg(e));
    exit(0);
}

Z3_context mk_context_custom(Z3_config cfg, Z3_error_handler err)
{
    Z3_context ctx;

    Z3_set_param_value(cfg, "MODEL", "true");
    ctx = Z3_mk_context(cfg);
    Z3_set_error_handler(ctx, err);

    return ctx;
}

Z3_context mk_context()
{
    Z3_config  cfg;
    Z3_context ctx;
    cfg = Z3_mk_config();
    ctx = mk_context_custom(cfg, error_handler);
    Z3_del_config(cfg);
    return ctx;
}

Z3_ast mk_var(Z3_context ctx, const char * name, Z3_sort ty)  
{
    Z3_symbol   s  = Z3_mk_string_symbol(ctx, name);
    return Z3_mk_const(ctx, s, ty); 
}

Z3_ast mk_int_var(Z3_context ctx, const char * name)
{
    Z3_sort ty = Z3_mk_int_sort(ctx);
    return mk_var(ctx, name, ty);
}

int main()
{
    Z3_context      ctx;
    Z3_func_decl    f;
    Z3_sort         int_sort;
    Z3_symbol       f_name;
    Z3_ast xVar, yVar;
    Z3_app bound[2];
    Z3_ast implication;
    Z3_sort       f_domain[2];

    // Make context.
    ctx = mk_context();

    int_sort    = Z3_mk_int_sort(ctx);
    f_name      = Z3_mk_string_symbol(ctx, "max_integer");
    f_domain[0] = int_sort;
    f_domain[1] = int_sort;
    f = Z3_mk_func_decl(ctx, f_name, 2, f_domain, int_sort);

    xVar = mk_int_var(ctx, "x");
    yVar = mk_int_var(ctx, "y");

    bound[0] = (Z3_app)xVar;
    bound[1] = (Z3_app)yVar;

    implication = Z3_mk_ite(ctx, Z3_mk_lt(ctx, xVar, yVar), xVar, yVar);

    Z3_mk_forall_const(ctx, 0, 2, bound, 0, 0, implication);

    // Delete the context.
    Z3_del_context(ctx);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9777381/c-api-for-quantifiers) may help.

Comment: You cannot use regular constants to represent the bound variables in the quantified clause, you need to make *bound* variables. See z3_mk_bound in the API.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I have read this post before, but it is little confusing to me. I tried to implement it in my code, but I didn't succeed compiling the code.

Comment: in my code I had `xVar = Z3_mk_bound(ctx, 0, int_sort);yVar = Z3_mk_bound(ctx, 1, int_sort);` but it didn't work.

Comment: also I checked for 2 sources 1. Z3 API for `Z3_mk_forall_const` and 2. [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13072081/quantifier-elimination-for-lia-in-z3-via-c-c-api), both say that we can use the const variables in bound argument.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting a type error because `implication` is an integer expression. The argument of a `forall` expression must be a Boolean expression. I'm assuming you are trying to create the formula

```
(forall ((x Int) (y Int)) (= (max_int x y) (ite (< y x) x y)))
```

Here is the modified example. Note that I also modified `Z3_mk_lt(ctx, xVar, yVar)` to `Z3_mk_lt(ctx, yVar, xVar)`. Otherwise, you would be defining the `min` function.

```c
int main()
{
    Z3_context      ctx;
    Z3_func_decl    f;
    Z3_sort         int_sort;
    Z3_symbol       f_name;
    Z3_ast xVar, yVar;
    Z3_app bound[2];
    Z3_ast ite;
    Z3_sort f_domain[2];
    Z3_ast f_app;
    Z3_ast eq;
    Z3_ast q;

    // Make context.
    ctx = mk_context();

    int_sort    = Z3_mk_int_sort(ctx);
    f_name      = Z3_mk_string_symbol(ctx, "max_integer");
    f_domain[0] = int_sort;
    f_domain[1] = int_sort;
    f = Z3_mk_func_decl(ctx, f_name, 2, f_domain, int_sort);

    xVar = mk_int_var(ctx, "x");
    yVar = mk_int_var(ctx, "y");

    bound[0] = (Z3_app)xVar;
    bound[1] = (Z3_app)yVar;

    // Create the application f(x, y)
    { Z3_ast args[2] = {xVar, yVar}; 
      f_app = Z3_mk_app(ctx, f, 2, args);
    }

    // Create the expression ite(y < x, x, y)
    ite = Z3_mk_ite(ctx, Z3_mk_lt(ctx, yVar, xVar), xVar, yVar);

    // Create the equality
    eq = Z3_mk_eq(ctx, f_app, ite);

    // Create quantifier
    q = Z3_mk_forall_const(ctx, 0, 2, bound, 0, 0, eq);

    printf("%s\n", Z3_ast_to_string(ctx, q));

    // Delete the context.
    Z3_del_context(ctx);

    return 0;
}
```